# New TV, Skyrim broke!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, monitor

I recently bought a 50" 4k Phillips TV, just plugged the PS3 into it to play Skyrim, but now when I look around the screen turns funnily, as if when I moved the stick it was set to snap to a certain degree turn almost. Anybody know a solution?

Comment: Sounds to me like it might be a TV setting, such as it's trying to upscale the PS3 content to 4k or similar. Have you read the manual for this new TV? Also, please update your question with the specific TV model number, as it'll help people answering your question.

Comment: I think I've sorted it tbh, been a bit of eager beaver and didn't update the ps3 so think it must be that although I haven't tried it yet coz it's just finished now but I checked the TV and it was using 720p as that's all skyrim supports.

Comment: Ok so the system update didn't do anything. There's still a delay from me pressing the stick to the actual game moving. The TV is a 6800er serie Phillips.

Comment: Tried a 3d compatible game and it works perfectly

Comment: I see a mention in this thread that [Skyrim on the PS3 has input lag when upscaling to 1080p](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61467217?page=1). Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: Out of interest, what version is your HDMI cable?

Comment: I'm not too sure on the hdmi cable but I checked the TV and it was at 720p resolution not 1080p. I found another forum basically saying that this range of TVs are all the same for gaming and it can only be minimised slightly and that's it. Looks like I'll be using the old TV from now on most likely.

Comment: I've just been on the Philips website and checked the supported resolutions, because it's a 4k TV, the hdmi output on all sources is 2160p, do you think if I use scart then it will fix the problem? Although it is a super slim ps3 so not sure if it has a scart input. Also this is at my girlfriends house so I'm not always there to test it. I have a ps4 at home but I just miss skyrim so much as I haven't gotten round to fixing my PC yet.